# Android(mono), TypeLoadException : " Could not load type 'CameraInfo' "

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, zxing

I used the below code piece to read barcode using Zxing barcode library which is downloaded from http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile. Application minVersion is selected as 2.3 and target version is selected as Automatic. I'am running the app on nexus 4 (Android 4.4.2)

```
    BarcodeButton.Click += async delegate 
    {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this);
        var result = await scanner.Scan();

        if (result != null)                 
            Toast.MakeText(this,"DONE",ToastLength.Short).Show();
    };
```

When I run the application, after pressing the barcodebutton this error log is obtained. What is the error? How can I solve it? :

```
                              ...
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ZXing.Net.Mobile[0x784bb038] -> mscorlib[0x777e2a10]: 9
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref TeleLib[0x784b8c58] -> zxing.monoandroid[0x784ba440]: 2
[Mono] The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
[Mono] Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x78801068].
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref zxing.monoandroid[0x784ba440] -> mscorlib[0x777e2a10]: 10
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ZXing.Net.Mobile[0x784bb038] -> Mono.Android[0x784bbb98]: 4
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ZXing.Net.Mobile[0x784bb038] -> zxing.monoandroid[0x784ba440]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref ZXing.Net.Mobile[0x784bb038] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4[0x784b9848]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref zxing.monoandroid[0x784ba440] -> Mono.Android[0x784bbb98]: 5
[] TypeRef ResolutionScope not yet handled (14) for .CameraInfo in image /data/data/TeleLib.TeleLib/files/.__override__/ZXing.Net.Mobile.dll
[Mono] The class CameraInfo could not be loaded, used in 
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CameraInfo'.
[MonoDroid] at Android.Views.ISurfaceHolderCallbackInvoker.n_SurfaceCreated_Landroid_view_SurfaceHolder_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005f>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c17a61df-f7d9-45dc-ba1c-dac5c5d9eb39 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
[mono] 
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CameraInfo'.
[mono]   at Android.Views.ISurfaceHolderCallbackInvoker.n_SurfaceCreated_Landroid_view_SurfaceHolder_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_holder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:c17a61df-f7d9-45dc-ba1c-dac5c5d9eb39 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CameraInfo'.
[mono-rt]   at Android.Views.ISurfaceHolderCallbackInvoker.n_SurfaceCreated_Landroid_view_SurfaceHolder_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_holder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:c17a61df-f7d9-45dc-ba1c-dac5c5d9eb39 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue and figured out that the ZXing.NET component requires Android version 2.3. Change your project to target 2.3 or newer, and this error will go away.

Comment: My problem is not because of versioning. I opened a new project, first add the reference and then copy my whole sources. After that it started working!!. But the previous one is not working(??).I compare the configurations 3 times and couldn't find any difference. Anyway it is working now.